# Removal of ASCII characters in datasteps

Tags: sas

Looking at [this](http://web.cs.mun.ca/~michael/c/ascii-table.html) and this code:

```
data Work.SomeDataset;
    set Work.SomeDataset;
    SomeColumn = compress(SomeColumn, byte(34));
    SomeColumn = compress(SomeColumn, byte(38));
run;
```

Am I right in thinking that this removes the characters `"` (byte(34)) and `&` (byte(38)) from SomeColumn? If so, is there a more efficient way of achieving this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is already fairly close to optimal, but for a slight improvement I'd suggest:

```
data Work.SomeDataset;
    set Work.SomeDataset;
    SomeColumn = compress(SomeColumn,'&"');
run;
```

This makes it clearer which characters are being removed and removes both in the same pass.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that removes those ascii characters.  You can do this in one COMPRESS call, by concatenating, and of course you could just pass `'&"'` to the function but I assume you have a reason for not doing so.

You might also want to use COMPBL to remove the extra spaces that might be created by this process, if that is a problem.

```
data Work.want;
  set Work.have;
  someColumn = compress(someColumn,byte(34)||byte(38));
  put SomeColumn=;
run;
```

You could also use UPDATE (SQL) or MODIFY (data step) to avoid rewriting the dataset...

```
proc sql;
  update have
    set someColumn = compress(someColumn,byte(34)||byte(38));
quit;
```

Perhaps more efficient, perhaps not; ultimately probably no different if you cannot use a WHERE statement to filter out cases that don't need updating, but if you can (if it's rare to have this for example) it might be more efficient.

Edit:
Modify looks like it's not the answer. In a quick test with 1e7 rows, MODIFY is strictly slower in real time AND has far more CPU time.

SQL UPDATE also is pretty slow, so I wouldn't use either of those unless you have a very rare update scenario (but test in your situation).

Answer (score 1):

You can put the characters into a single call.

```
data have;
format a $12.;
a = "A" || byte(34) || "B";
output;
a = "A" || byte(34) || "B" || byte(36) || "C";
output;
run;

data want;
set have;
b = compress(a,byte(34)||byte(36));
run;
```